# Magento SOAP C# login issue in Visual Studio 11 (Metro)

Tags: c#, magento, soap, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build a Metro app that can get products off a Magento installation.

When I get to the login part in Visual Studio 2010 it works fine:

```
string sessionId = proxy.login("user", "pass");
```

However, when I try the same code in Visual Studio 11, it doesn't give me the login option, rather the loginAsync, like so:

```
string sessionId = proxy.loginAsync("user", "pass");
```

If I use this option (which has the valid parameters of the regular "login"), VS11 gives me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to
>   'string'

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `await` modifier

```
loginResponse sessionId = await proxy.loginAsync("user", "pass");
```

**EDIT**

It looks like a lot of the APIs you're using have gone from being synchronous to asynchronous.  The asynchronous versions are coming back as `Task<string>` instead of simply `string`.  Whenever that happens you have 2 options on how to get the `string` or whatever data out of the `Task<T>`.

- Use `await` on the expression.  This is non-blocking
- Call `.Result` on the task.  This is blocking

Comment: This:

"The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'."

Comment: @AlexGorcea did you try making the method async?

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @AlexGorcea you add the modifier `async` in the same place you would put `public` for example.  Just before the return type.

Comment: Alright, now I got another error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'FancyWin8.Fancy.loginResponse' to 'string'`

Comment: @AlexGorcea looks like they changed the return type from string to `loginResponse`.  The sessionId is likely inside that particular object.  Try changing `sessionId` to be `loginResponse response` and inspecting the members with intellisense

Comment: @AlexGorcea i don't exactly know. I would assume that the session id would be burried somewhere in that response. I can't find any API documentation to reference to look for it.

Comment: This is the loginResponse, from what I can tell:

` public partial class loginResponse {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:Magento", Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string result;
        
        public loginResponse() {
        }
        
        public loginResponse(string result) {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }
`

Comment: I used response.result instead of sessionId and I got rid of the error. But now I have a different one. In `catalogProductReturnEntity prod = proxy.catalogProductInfoAsync(response.result, "BLU001", "", fetchattrib, "");`, I get the following error: **"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FancyWin8.Fancy.catalogProductInfoResponse>' to 'FancyWin8.Fancy.catalogProductReturnEntity'**

Comment: @AlexGorcea try using `await` again or simply call .Result on the return of the `proxy.catalogProductInfoAsync(response.result, "BLU001", "", fetchattrib, "").Result`

Comment: Using `await` only removes the **System.Threading.Tasks.Task** of the error. The rest is still there. Wouldn't it be easier NOT to use asynchronous programming? :)

Comment: `await proxy.catalogProductInfoAsync(response.result, "BLU001", "", fetchattrib, "")` gives me the same error, while `await proxy.catalogProductInfoAsync(response.result, "BLU001", "", fetchattrib, "").Result` gives me **Cannot await 'FancyWin8.Fancy.catalogProductInfoResponse'**

Comment: @AlexGorcea use `await` or `.Result` but not both together

Comment: They both give me the following error: **
Cannot implicitly convert type 'FancyWin8.Fancy.catalogProductInfoResponse' to 'FancyWin8.Fancy.catalogProductReturnEntity'**

Comment: @AlexGorcea sounds like you have declared the variable as `catalogProductReturnEntity` instead of `catalogProductInfoResponse`

Comment: You're right. It's squeaky clean now. Thank you very much for your help. :)